# Difference between executing StreamTasks in the same instance v/s multiple instances

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Say I have a topic with 3 partitions
**Method 1:** I run one instance of Kafka Streams, it starts 3 tasks [0_0,0_1,0_2] and each of these tasks consume from one partition.
**Method 2:** I spin up three instance of the same streams application, here again three tasks are started but now, it is distributed among the 3 instances that was created.
Which method is preferable and why?
*In method 1 do all the tasks run as a part of the same thread, and in method 2, they run on different threads, or is it different?*

Consider that the streams application has a very simple topology, and does only mapping of values from a single stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a single `KafkaStreams` instance runs one thread, thus in "Method 1" all three tasks are executed by a single thread. In "Method 2" each task is executed by its own thread. Note, that you can also configure multiple thread pre `KafkaStreams` instance via `num.stream.threads` configuration parameter. If you set it to `3` for "Method 1" both method are more or less the same. How many threads you need, depends on your workload, ie, how many messages you need to process per time unit and how expensive the computation is. It also depends on the hardware: for a single-core CPU, it may not make sense to configure more than one thread, but you should deploy multiple instances on multiple machines to get more hardware. Hence, if your workload is lightweight one single-threaded instance might be enough.

Also note, that you may be network bound. For this case, starting more thread would not help, but you want to scale out to multiple machines, too.

The last consideration is fault-tolerance. Even if a single thread/instance may be powerful enough to not lag, what should happen if the instance crashes? If you only have one instance, the whole computation goes down. If you run two instances, the second instance would take over all the work and your application stays online.